GitHub PagesでCSSが反映されない
GitHub Pagesでwebサイトを作ったのですが、cssがどうしても反映されません。
要因と対策を教えてください。よろしくお願いします。
HTML側のコードはこれにしてあります
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kongou173.github.io/Coresync-bot/css/style.css" />

なんで反映されないのか教えてください。
できれば修正後のコードを貼ってくれれば幸いです。
問題のリポジトリ
https://github.com/Kongou173/Coresync-bot
Webサイト(GitHub pages)
https://kongou173.github.io/Coresync-bot/

リポジトリを覗いてみると、CSS の保存されているディレクトリ (フォルダ名) が、小文字ではなく大文字の "CSS" のようです。HTML で指定するパスを再度確認してみてください。
修正後:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kongou173.github.io/Coresync-bot/CSS/style.css" />

